# Not able to install Java-7 on Debian machine

Tags: java, ubuntu, debian, java-7

I am not able to install `Java-7` on `Google Cloud Engine`. Initially i added a `ppa` repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
```

Got this:

```
Hit http://ftp.debian.org wheezy-backports/non-free Translation-en/DiffIndex
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net wheezy/main Sources
404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net wheezy/main amd64 Packages
404  Not Found
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net wheezy/main Translation-en
Fetched 473 B in 2s (236 B/s)
W: GPG error: http://www.duinsoft.nl debs Release: The following signatures couldn't be    
verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY E18CE6625CB26B26
W: Failed to fetch 
http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu/dists/wheezy/main/source/Sources  404    
Not Found
W: Failed to fetch   
http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu/dists/wheezy/main/binary-amd64/Packages    
404  Not Found
 E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used 
 instead.
```

To make sure why `apt-get update` is not working. I removed `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`
 `webupd8team-java-wheezy.list` and then run `apt-get update`. Everything works fine!

Now, Is there any other way to install `java-7` on remote machine using `CLI`. I googled but didn't find any relevant info upon it (except installing java-7 manually).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have an specific requirement to use Java 7 you could install Java 8 with the [webupd8 repository](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/03/how-to-install-oracle-java-8-in-debian.html) in you Debian version. The steps are quite different from the ones you followed for the Java 7 version, though.

As you probably know, having JDK 8 installed doesn't mean your application needs to be JRE 8 compliant: you can set the compliance level in Eclipse (or your IDE) at any time.

Comment: @AmitPal: Have you updated the GPG key? http://www.raspians.com/Knowledgebase/the-following-signatures-couldnt-be-verified-because-the-public-key-is-not-available-no_pubkey/